# hadoop fs -put command

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs, put

I have constructed a single-node Hadoop environment on CentOS using the Cloudera CDH repository.  When I want to copy a local file to HDFS, I used the command:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -put /root/MyHadoop/file1.txt /
```

But,the result depressed me:

```
put: '/root/MyHadoop/file1.txt': No such file or directory
```

I'm sure this file does exist.

Please help me,Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As user `hdfs`, do you have access rights to `/root/` (in your local hdd)?. Usually you don't.
You must copy `file1.txt` to a place where local `hdfs` user has read rights before trying to copy it to HDFS.

Try:

```
cp /root/MyHadoop/file1.txt /tmp
chown hdfs:hdfs /tmp/file1.txt
# older versions of Hadoop
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -put /tmp/file1.txt /
# newer versions of Hadoop
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -put /tmp/file1.txt /
```

--- edit:

Take a look at [the cleaner roman-nikitchenko's answer bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002128/582789).

Comment: Thanks,but I tried to move this file to another place,type the follow command:           {sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -put /home/skfeng/Downloads/hadoop-book-master/test-data/ch1/file1.txt /} it still doesn't work and has the same results: {put: `/home/skfeng/Downloads/hadoop-book-master/test-data/ch1/file1.txt': No such file or directory
}

Comment: And does user `hdfs` have access rights to the home of the user `skfeng`?

Comment: Yes! I understand!User **hdfs** have no access to home of other users,I make a new directory for **hdfs**,and it works!Thank you very much!:)

Answer (score 18):

I had the same situation and here is my solution:

```
 HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hdfs fs -put /root/MyHadoop/file1.txt /
```

Advantages:

1. You don't need `sudo`.
2. You don't need actually appropriate local user 'hdfs' at all.
3. You don't need to copy anything or change permissions because of previous points.

Comment: I like this solution, but I always forget what is the environment variable name :P +1

Comment: Thanks, i have to use DFS instead of FS, like this  : 

HADOOP_USER_NAME=PUT_YOUR_USER_HERE hdfs dfs -put /source/xxx/yyy /destination/zzz

Answer (score 9):

try to create a dir in the HDFS by usig: `$ hadoop fs -mkdir your_dir`
and then put it into it `$ hadoop fs -put /root/MyHadoop/file1.txt your_dir`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a command for writing df directly to hdfs file system in python script:

```
df.write.save('path', format='parquet', mode='append')
```

mode can be append | overwrite

If you want to put in in hdfs using shell use this command:
hdfs dfs -put  /local_file_path_location  /hadoop_file_path_location

You can then check on localhost:50070 UI for verification

---