# Copying a file to a folder in hdfs showing: No such file or directory - quickstart.cloudera

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs, hue

I have installed a docker in my ubuntu 16. Inside that I installed cloudera quickstart (hostname=quickstart.cloudera). I need to copy a file into a folder in hdfs named stackexchange.

I have given the command

```
 [root@quickstart /]# hdfs dfs -put /home/myuser/Stack/Tags.xml stackexchange
```

But it's showing a error as

```
 put: `/home/myuser/Stack/Tags.xml': No such file or directory
```

What could be the issue? Is docker unable to copy from a local folder? I am very new in hadoop and docker..

Comment: what's the absolute path for the folder stackexchange?

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484939/hadoop-fs-put-command

Comment: if I run this command ->  hdfs dfs -ls  it will show the result as -->  drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs supergroup          0 2017-08-23 06:54 stackexchange

Comment: you are trying to copy the file from the host system from inside the docker ? or does the file reside within the docker instance?

Comment: At first I tried to copy from the local system.After that I uploaded the file in /user/cloudera using hue. Then I tried hdfs dfs -put /user/cloudera/Tags.xml stackexchange . Still the same result